# TCP Persistent Connections with HTTP?

Tags: http, tcp

So i thought with HTTP 1.1 your TCP connections are sustained for as long are you are communicating with that server? How does it actually work, how does the TCP connection know when you are done writing into the socket? Any formation would be awesome, i have done research but i cant find what im looking for short of reading the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

See [section 8.1 of RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1). Basically, HTTP 1.1 treats all connections as persistent but the langauage of the RFC doesn't mandate this behaviour, since it uses the word "SHOULD". If it was mandated, it would use "MUST".

However, the RFC does not specify in detail how an implementation does this. As can be seen from the [HTTP Persistent Connection page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), Apache's default timeout (beyond which it returns persistent connections for other uses) may be as low as five seconds.  (though this is almost certainly configurable, given all the other knobs and dials that Apache provides).

In other words, it's meant for numerous requests to the same address within a short time frame, so as to not waste time opening and closing a bucket-load of sessions where one will do. Increasing this timeout is not a "free ride", since resources are tied up while the connection is held open. In an environment where you expect lots of incoming clients, tying up these resources can be fatal to performance.

Comment: so if i add a keepalive header to my packet i should keep the TCP session open for as long as the server supports ?

Comment: @Taylor, no, it's actually for as long as the server _allows,_ which is subtly different. Both server and client has to agree to keep the session open. I should add that you would be unwise to try and increase this timeout, it's not a free ride. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout if you want to know how to do it in Apache and consider carefully the warning there.

Answer (score 0):

The typical implementation is that the HTTP server will have a timeout (typically called [KeepAliveTimeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout) or [such](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#keepalive_timeout)) after which it will close an idle connection.

A server which reserves a thread or an entire process per connection (such as apache with the usual mpm_prefork or mpm_worker), keepalives are usually disabled entirely or kept quite short (a few seconds). For an event-based server such as nginx which uses much less memory per connection, the keepalive timeout can be left at a much higher value (typically a minute or so).